# Sum of roots of unity with linear coefficients

Tags: roots-of-unity

Given that $n$ is a positive integer and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$, how do you prove that
$a_0+a_1\omega+a_2\omega^2+...+a_{n-1}\omega^{n-1}=0$ is only true when all the $a$'s are equal?

Comment: I must be missing something. What if $n = 4$ and $a_0 = a_2 = 1$ and $a_1 = a_3 = 2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Amended result**.  If $n$ is prime and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$ and $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ are integers and
$$a_0+a_1\omega+a_2\omega^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}\omega^{n-1}=0\ ,$$
then $a_0=a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{n-1}$.

**Proof**.  Under the stated conditions, $\omega$ is a root of the integer polynomial
$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}\ .$$
Therefore $f(z)$ is a (polynomial) multiple of the minimal polynomal of $\omega$, which is
$$m(z)=1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1}\ .$$
Since $f(z)$ has the same degree as $m(z)$, it must in fact be a *constant* multiple of $m(z)$, and the result follows.

See also [this book](https://www.routledge.com/Irrationality-and-Transcendence-in-Number-Theory/Angell/p/book/9780367628376), problem 3.26 (shameless free plug).

Comment: +1. I'm chagrined not to have realized that's what was probably meant.